# i386 x86_64 architecture Assembly language no symbol error

Tags: debugging, assembly, makefile, symbols, kate

just started out assembly programming, after compiling it with nasm and when i open the file with `gdb ./myfile`, (No debugging symbols found in ./sandbox (its my file name))

tried many commands from terminal objdump, nm and all, no debugging symbol found in ./sandbox

ASM code

```cpp
section .data
section .text

    global _start

_start:

    nop

; put your experiments between here

; put your experiments between here

    nop

section .bss
```

Code from makefile

```cpp
sandbox: sandbox.o
    ld -m elf_i386 -s -o sandbox sandbox.o
sandbox.o: sandbox.asm
    nasm -f elf -g -F dwarf sandbox.asm -l sanbox.lst
```

error getting from gdb objdump

(No debugging symbols found in ./sandbox (its my file name))

Comment: What do you think `-s` does in the `ld` command line?

Comment: You don't need debug symbols to debug asm.  Just use `starti` to start the program and pause at the first instruction.  Use `stepi` aka `si` to single-step.  Use `layout reg` to see disassembly and registers.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has a section at the bottom on debugging.